# How to delete and reinstall agrarian skies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My agrarian skies have stopped to work because I've tried to reinstall not enough items when not enough items stopped working for me, and now I just want to start over again with the mod being as it was when I first started.

Comment: IIRC in the feed the beast launcher there's a way to force it "update" without losing your save data.

Answer (score 1):

The files for Agrarian Skies are, by default, stored in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\FTB\AgrarianSkiesHQ`. To completely restore Agrarian Skies, backup your saves folder (or don't, if you want to start completely over) and delete this folder. When you launch Agrarian Skies again, you'll download the whole thing again. It will take a while, yes, but it's the best way to make sure everything is restored completely to default.

Comment: But when I try to delete everything it ses somthing like: you can't delete this because it's open in another program

Comment: Do you have Agrarian Skies open? It won't work if that's the case. If not... I'd restart your computer. I'm not sure what else would have control of the files in that folder other than the FTB launcher or Minecraft.

Comment: Ok I will try it was the mods that was in the fab folder that I couldn't delete but maybe u don't have to delete the mods to start over maybe u only have to delete the one folder where the agrarian skiesHQ is. I will try this tomorrow. Thx!